# How does an Ethereum PoS node software resolve social consensus?

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-stake, consensus, casper, openethereum

As a new user, when I join the Ethereum network and want to know what the consensus chain is, I have to rely on social consensus, right — like for example I get two completely different states and both claim their one is the valid one? It's not like in PoW, that there is an objective answer to the question what the consensus state is, there is an subjective component involved or in other words a social consensus, right?

But how does a new node joining the network actually resolve this situation? The node software does not have information about the social consensus, right? It seems like nodes always resolve it correctly even though the node software actually does not have any information about the social consensus or does the node software have some — I don't know checkpoints or hardcoded nodes from which it pulls the state in it? In PoW this is straightforward (longest chain rule with the most work), but how does an Ethereum PoS node end up every time at the consensus chain when there is actually more social consensus involved compared to Bitcoin just to decide between two states initially?

Comment: I think I found the answer, but if somebody has a better answer, please tell me: "Fortunately, for them, the solution is simple: the first time they sign up, and every time they stay offline for a very very long time, they need only get a recent block hash from a friend, a blockchain explorer, or simply their software provider, and paste it into their blockchain client as a "checkpoint". They will then be able to securely update their view of the current state from there." --https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/11/25/proof-stake-learned-love-weak-subjectivity